# Is there a shortcut for incrementing a value and setting one at the same time?

Tags: c#

Not an easy question to word.

Basically, is there a way to combine these two statements into one:

```
value++;
Value2 = Value;
```

So basically:

```
Value 2 = value++
```

But, where it increments value as well.

Can it be done?

Comment: `Value 2 = value++` I don't think this is valid code for C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
value2 = ++value;
```

See: [++ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)

Prefix increment operation: The result of the operation is the value of the operand after it has been incremented.

Answer (score 1):

```
value2 = ++value; //assign the incremented value to value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this one?

```
int i = 1;
int j = ++i;
Console.WriteLine(i); // 2
Console.WriteLine(j); // 2
```

Note: this will change both values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can combine those two..
value2=++value.